# AVAssetWriterInput output settings not rendering valid NSData

Tags: iphone, ios, audio, avassetwriter

I am using AVAssetWriterInput to take an mp3 file from the user, and email it (DRM free only). I got the process to work when using PCM, but when I try mp3, or m4a, or caf, I either get a file that doesn't work, or I get empty data. I think it is due to my output settings. The output settings used that draw no data are below. I am open to changing all of it. Thanks!

```
    NSDictionary *outputSettings = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                [ NSNumber numberWithInt: kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC], AVFormatIDKey,
                                [ NSNumber numberWithInt: 1 ], AVNumberOfChannelsKey,
                                [ NSNumber numberWithFloat: 44100.0 ], AVSampleRateKey,
                                [ NSData dataWithBytes: &channelLayout length: sizeof( AudioChannelLayout ) ], AVChannelLayoutKey,
                                [ NSNumber numberWithInt: 64000 ], AVEncoderBitRateKey,
                                nil];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apple provides no API for *writing* mp3 files, perhaps because mp3 is just headerless packets and simply writing out the raw packets works fine.

As for writing out AAC data in m4a/caf containers, I'm not sure - but that AVEncoderBitRateKey should definitely not be there as you're not encoding anything - you're just passing data through. So why not forget about AVAssetWriter and use an AVAssetExportSession with a passthrough preset?

Comment: Thanks a lot! I got it working with AVAssetExportSession, however, it is extremely slow. The background thread takes forever to start up. Is this common?